# How much does GRANT permission checking affect MySQL performance?

Tags: mysql

I was going through this article :
http://www.ajaxline.com/32-tips-to-speed-up-your-mysql-queries

at point#4 , it states :

> Using simpler permissions when you issue GRANT statements enables
>   MySQL  to reduce permission-checking overhead when clients execute
>   statements.

Questions:

1. How does this impact performance ?
2. What is meant by "simpler permissions" ? eg. if I have a root user with all permissions,.eg. create or alter table on database, and a "appDbUser" for my web application, how shall I grant SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT permissions to appDbUser to comply with what has been suggested in the forementioned text.

Comment: simpler permissions means that you don't have several granular per-table and per-column permissions and just database level permissions.

Comment: Personally Id focus on your security and business requirements, and not worry too much about permission checking. View it as an unavoidable operating cost. If your permissions are unwieldy and complicated, then sure, try to simplify them. But a handful of permissions are not going to have a huge impact on performance, especially when there are usually much more significant reasons why a query or server is slow.

Comment: @carpii , this question is not related to my development requirement. I wanted to know this from curiousity, and to understand the underlying mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to profile it and see for yourself....

```
-- enable profile gathering
SET PROFILING = 1;

SELECT <query involving complex set of column and table permissions>;

SHOW PROFILE

--or SHOW PROFILES, and then SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 2 etc

-- turn profiling back off again
SET PROFILING = 0;
```

This will present a table showing each stage of the query being executed, along with the duration. You will probably see that even with fairly complex permissions, the time is not significant compared to the execution, sorting and grouping of the query